# Two instance of the same sencha touch application

Tags: jsp, sencha-touch

I have this code in a jsp file, the first time it runs OK. But the second time it throws an error.

```
function ${namespace}addAppInternal(divIdStr) {    
    Ext.application({
    models: [
        'OldGridDataModel'
    ],
    stores: [
        'DataStore',
        'OldDataStore'
    ],
    views: [
        'Main',
        'TouchTreeGrid'
    ],
    controllers: [
        'TouchGridController'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: '/o3-parts-web/senchaGridTouch/app',


    launch: function() {

        var cont = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'                                                                                                               
                },
                renderTo: <%=divIdStr %>,
                //itemId: 'main',
                user: '<%=username %>',
                ticket: '<%=ticket %>',
                height : 300,
                id: String(<%=divIdStr %>),
                divT: document.getElementById("${prefsHelperDiv}")
            });
        cont.add({html:'test'});
    }


});
```

The error is:

> "Uncaught Error: Ext.setup has already been called before"

I know that Ext.application() runs Ext.setup().

Why can't I run it twice? And how can I avoid this situation?

Comment: Can you add a bit more information, why you would want to start the same webapp at the same time? That might help. And please add some info about having id and renderTo the same target.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Ext.application twice you can only call it once that is why you are getting that error. You cannot call it twice because it is a Singleton & an application is only an application it cannot be two applications if that makes any sense. I suggest you initialize the function on load then call whatever you want within the function you have defined.

Hope it helps